# Extra line printed by bubble sort code

Tags: java, bubble-sort

Writing a bubble sort algorithm in java for school and randomly getting an extra line printed to the screen, and I can't figure out why it is doing this. Here is my code.[Code result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O81O.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the # of numbers to be sorted: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter 1 for ints or 2 for doubles: ");
        int intdou = input.nextInt();
        if (intdou == 1) {
            int x = 0;
            int[] num = new int[number];
            for (int q = 0; q < number; q++) {
                System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                num[q] = input.nextInt();
            }
            for (int w = 0; w < number; w++) {
                for (int e = 1; e < (number - w); e++) {
                    if (num[e - 1] > num[e]) {
                        x = num[e - 1];
                        num[e - 1] = num[e];
                        num[e] = x;
                        for (int r = 0; r < number; r++) {
                            System.out.print(num[r] + ", ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        } else if (intdou == 2) {
            double x = 0;
            double[] num = new double[number];
            for (int q = 0; q < number; q++) {
                System.out.print("Enter number: ");
                num[q] = input.nextInt();
            }
            for (int w = 0; w < number; w++) {
                for (int e = 1; e < (number - w); e++) {
                    if (num[e - 1] > num[e]) {
                        x = num[e - 1];
                        num[e - 1] = num[e];
                        num[e] = x;
                        for (int r = 0; r < number; r++) {
                            System.out.print(num[r] + ", ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the extra blank line? Just move "System.out.print("\n");" inside the if block.